# If else in \newtheoremstyle

Tags: conditionals, theorems, newtheorem

I'd like to make a custom theorem style such that would have the condition in it.

To be more specific, when there is an optional argument in my theorem environment, the title should be taken from that, otherwise no changes.

I've been trying to do the following, but I failed in tries.

```
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {}
  {1em}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {
    \ifthenelse{#3}{
        \thmnote{#3}
    }{
        \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`amsthm`'s internal macro `\@ifempty` is what you need. Alternatively, you can use `\ifstrempty{<string>}{<true code>}{<false code>}` from `etoolbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mytheorem}
  {\topsep}
  {\topsep}
  {}
  {1em}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {%
    \@ifempty{#3}
      {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
      {\thmname{#3}}%
  }
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{mytheorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
  content
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}[Title]
  content
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!